# Help with replicating Fionn Ferreira's microplastic experiment

Tags: plastics

Hi I am an eighth grade student doing my first science fair project on microplastics. The first step of my experiment is replicating F. Ferriera's microplastic experiment where he used magnetite to remove microplastics from water. The problem is that I have been unsuccessful in doing this. I have used plastic glitter, microbeads and epoxy resin. None of these were attracted to the iron filings in water nor were they removed when I stirred them together and inserted a magnetic rod. What am I doing wrong? I don't think it's the plastics, is it the filings? I tried inserting a magnetite rock to see is that did anything, no luck. Help!

Comment: Apparently he uses or used ferrofluids, which not magnetite only. It is a suspension of magnetite in some fluid. The size of microplastics should be very small, ideally not visible to your eyes.

Comment: Add more details about your experiment. Did you use a ferrofluid or just magnetite particles. Magnetite particles alone will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding quickly. I just used iron filings. I looked on Amazon and found a ferrofluid for purchase. I am going to add 1/4 teaspoon of blue epoxy resin pigment to 1 cup water and stir. Then I will add 1/4 teaspoon of the ferrofluid to the beaker and stir. I then place my Magnetic chip collector (long magnet) in the beaker and pray that it collects everything (ferrofluid and all the blue epoxy resin).  My 'real' experiment was going to be designing a way to efficiently remove the plastic from the ferro-solution, like a sustainable filter. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I am not sure about your proposed experiment in the comment (never did this). The key point is that the plastic has to be really small. Your original plastic "particles" were pretty large. I am sure your teacher must be advising you correctly. Also iron filings are *not* magnetite.

Answer (score -2):

Cool science project!

What are ferrofluids?
These are magnetic liquids. Imagine a liquid that a magnet can pull. They're made by mixing oil and magnetite (a kind of magnetic rock). Ferreira found out that these magnetic liquids love to stick to microplastics when they are in water.

How did he do it?
He added the oil and magnetite (which together make the ferrofluid) to water. Then, he put in a bunch of microplastics. When he stirred it all up, the microplastics stuck to the ferrofluid.

Next, he used a magnet to pull out the ferrofluid. Since the microplastics were stuck to the ferrofluid, they got pulled out too! And voila, the water was a lot cleaner.

Did it work well?
Yes! Ferreira tested this over 950 times and managed to remove 88% of the microplastics. That's even better than he thought he'd do!

Lab Technique: Always prioritize safety. When I was your age I got a fair number of burns, cuts, and scares and destroyed plenty of good equipment. Wear safety gear always, and remember that gloves themselves will react with some chemicals. Never underestimate the power of taking a few deep breaths and really thinking things out.

Ask for Help: If you're stuck or unsure about something, ask your teacher or an adult. Adult supervision is highly recommended.

Sources: http://www.oceansplasticleanup.com/Projects_Plastics_Oceans_Cleaning/Fionn_Ferreira_Google_Science_Fair_Education_Prize_Ocean_Microplastics_Cleaning.htm

https://www.businessinsider.com/microplastics-water-pollution-solution-from-google-2019-8

https://www.fionnferreira.com/

Comment: This doesn't address the key question at all. It merely restates the experiment in a very verbose and meaningless way.